# Is there a way to use MPI_Reduce with dynamic size of send buffer?

Tags: c, mpi, reduce, openmpi

I would like to use the "MPI_Reduce" function with a variable number of elements for each process.

For example.

We have 4 processes with an allocated buffer with a dynamic size.

```
P (0) size buffer = 21

P (1) size buffer = 24

P (2) size buffer = 21

P (3) size buffer = 12
```

I would like to reduce the values ​​of these elements on the processor with rank 0.

In my thoughts I would like to allocate a receive buffer of a size equal to the maximum of objects to be received by a process (in this case 24) and use that to retrieve the values ​​from the various processes.

There is a way in
which is it possible to do without increasing the execution times too much?

I am using Open MPI 2.1.1 in C, Thanks.

Comment: what is the semantic you expect from such a reduction?

Comment: I an array of a structure. I just need to iterate for each element to store the information in a hashmap. I would like to iterate the data by receiving the structures process by process to avoid allocating a buffer as large as the sum of all the elements.

Comment: are you sure your expectations of `reduce` can be fulfilled by the standard `MPI_Reduce()`?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not an expert on this. I believe that by defining my operation I can achieve my goal. Otherwise, is there any way you can advise me?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reduction variant that works with different numbers of elements per rank in MPI. It wouldn't know what to fill in for missing operands in the reduction operation. It's pretty straightforward to write though, just as you suggested:

- Determine the maximum buffer size
- Allocate max-sized buffer on each rank, copy in local buffer, pad with whatever the neutral element of your reduction operation is
- Run reduction on the now equal-sized buffers